# I can not connect through RPC port bitcoind

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli

I have set up bitcoind, and I am able to run bitcoin-cli commands, I am also able to make request through RPC.

curl --user username:password --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getblockchaininfo", "params": [] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:18332

It also works. But connecting through the public ip just return Connection refused.

curl --user username:password --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getblockchaininfo", "params": [] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://public-ip:18332

It returns

curl: (7) Failed to connect to external-ip port 18332: Connection refused

Config file as follows.

server=1

rpcport=9776

rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0

rpcbind=0.0.0.0

txindex=1

Comment: Looks like the host can't resolve the "external-ip" host?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing the exact same behaviour with bitcoin core 23 on both local and public network. On the local machine all works fine, but using an IP does not need to be resolved. FW and forwarding should be fine. Did you solve this? Can it be that curl demands https protocol or something like that?

Comment: Yes I found. Email: isti.ru.cse@gmail.com